# PouchDB and Vue.js integration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pouchdb, nosql

Did anyone of you integrate PouchDB / vue-pouch-db within your Vue.js app?
I got an error when defining PouchDB database.

I had used below definitions:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchDB'
or
import PouchDB from 'vue-pouch-db'
or
const PouchDB = require('vue-pouch-db')

const db = new PouchDB('database_name')
or
const db = PouchDB('database_name')
```

None of them works for me.

Errors:

- when declaring new PouchDB = > PouchDB is not a constructor
- when declaring PouchDB = > PouchDB is not a function

What is the proper way to initialize PouchDB in Vue ??
Thanks a lot !

Comment: https://github.com/QurateInc/vue-pouch-db

Comment: Thanks for the link reference

Answer (score 1):

In order to initialize PouchDB in Vue.js (2) you should:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser'
let localDB = new PouchDB('mylocaldb');
```

Of course, before using the certain package you must install it, e.g. via npm: `npm install pouchdb-browser`

Answer (score 0):

just add default, if you get this constructor is not a function

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;
```

i am using vue with pouchdb ,it works great because i am getting same problem like you